# How to capture chrome browser close event in GWT?

Tags: gwt

Trying to capture browser close event in Chrome. tried below code for Chrome and event doesn't get fired when closing browser but works in Internet explorer.

```
Window.addCloseHandler(new CloseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClose(CloseEvent event) {
        SC.say("on window close event");
    }
});

Window.addWindowClosingHandler(new ClosingHandler() {
     @Override
      public void onWindowClosing(ClosingEvent event) {
        SC.say("on window closing event");
      }
});
```

how to capture the browser close event for Chrome in GWT?

Comment: Both `addCloseHandler` and `addWindowClosingHandler` works for me. You can try to set a break point in Chrome debug console to stop on `SC.say` lines. BTW: what does `SC.say` method do?

Comment: SC.say method is like alert in java script. are you able debug GWT code in Chrome debug console?? if yes can you please help me how to do it?

Comment: Assuming you have Source Maps enabled, in short: in Chrome press `F12`, select `Source` tab, press `Ctrl`+`P` to select `.java` source file, click on line number to toggle break-point. Or read [this](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/superdevmode.html) or [that](http://www.g-widgets.com/2017/06/29/quick-tip-debugging-a-gwt-application-using-chrome-dev-tools/).

Comment: Could you try to call setMessage on the ClosingEvent? The [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload#Example) notes `Chrome requires returnValue to be set`.

Comment: @andi tried setting setMessage on ClosingEvent didn't work.

Comment: @Adam tried to enable source maps but the launch URL is not generating in development mode, my application is deployed in Tomcat, but i tried setting up debug environment in eclipse, any pointer like why i am not getting the URL, sure i am missing something

Comment: It's too complicated to explain debugging in a comment. Try Google. BTW: are you sure that you are allowed to show alert (SC.say) on window closing? Try to do something else, like writing to log/console for example.